# Magento remove table prefix

Tags: database

We want to delete/remove the Magento table prefix.

How can this be done? Is there a script available to do this in one-go?

Essentialy changing the table `myprefix_catalog_category` to `catalog_category`

We have had the prefix since 1.3 - but it is causing us too much problems when running scripts or extensions where one forgot to respect it. Removing it seems a lot more logical then.

Comment: what do your mean by "remove table prefix"? You have tabels like "mg_catalog_...." and you want them to be "catalog_...."?

Comment: I thought it was important to add this. See my answer and add to it if you find necessary

Comment: This is not really magento related. it's a db related question.

Comment: Following Link could be helpful:

 - http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13259/sql-command-to-remove-prefix-from-a-set-of-tables

Answer (score 2):

Steps:

- Make a database backup
- Disable caching
- Save this file on your server ([download here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5e36e4b79985abc14ace))
- Edit settings in the file
- Run the file in dryrun modus first (upload and run from browser)
- If you are satisfied: change dryrun to `false` and run again
- All done!
- Go to app/etc/local.xml and modify the table prefix (to empty)

Don't forget to reset `opcache` and reset all caches before it will work.

- Enable caching afterwards

You're done.

*UPDATE*. Script can be updated to support rename

Answer (score 2):

In phpMyAdmin select all tables, then `With Selected.. -> Replace table prefix` would surely be quicker than an export and re-imports.

Then edit your local.xml